# How to forward email after sending?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I use `Application_ItemSend` to trigger a userform with some inputs, then I want to forward the email using some of those inputs.

What I'm currently doing works if I send a new email rather than forward the original. I assume the original email is not sent until the ItemSend macro finishes and I can't forward an email that hasn't been sent yet.

How can I write a macro that will run after the email is sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right avenue - you need to wait until the item is sent out. Typically Outlook puts sent items to the `Sent Items` folder, so you can hook up the `ItemAdd` event on the `Sent Items` folder and forward the original sent email.

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items 

Public Sub Initialize_handler()  
 Set myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items  
End Sub  

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)  
 Dim myOlMItem As Outlook.MailItem  
 myOlMItem = Item.Forward()
 myOlMItem.Recipients.Add "Eugene Astafiev" 
 myOlMItem.Send  
End Sub
```

Note, users or other add-ins (VBA macros) can set up a custom folder for keeping sent items in Outlook. In that case you need to check out the [MailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.savesentmessagefolder) property which returns or sets a `Folder` object that represents the folder in which a copy of the email message will be saved after being sent. So, you need to set up a hook on that folder too. You can do that in the `ItemSend` event handler.